# Creating QGIS Shapefile in PyCharm leaving some attributes NULL

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyqt, pycharm

I've created the shapefile and can manually enter in all the attributes to come in fine, but when I call it any other way (which I will need to do), the values for the floating types appear as NULL, even after converting to str or int.

When I print `dato.iloc[0].tolist()`, it spits out the first row of data as a list, and looks as follows: ['1', '1', '31isk', 4613427, 413588.12200000003, 1.19, 'sand'].

If I have `feat.setAttributes(dato.iloc[0].tolist())`, all values except for the three floats come in fine. If I print and copy the resulting string into feat.setAttributes, it will add the attribute perfectly okay. This is only a quikc fix and not possible when there are hundreds of more attributes to add.

So again, this does NOT work: `dato.iloc[0].tolist()`

But this DOES work: `feat.setAttributes(['1', '1', '31isk', 4613427, 413588.12200000003, 1.19, 'sand'])`

This is all done within PyCharm. Fields are as follows (Northing, Easting, and Altitude all appear NULL):

```
layerFields = QgsFields()
layerFields.append(QgsField('Transect', QVariant.String))
layerFields.append(QgsField('PointNumber', QVariant.String))
layerFields.append(QgsField('SubClass', QVariant.String))
layerFields.append(QgsField('Northing', QVariant.String))
layerFields.append(QgsField('Easting', QVariant.String))
layerFields.append(QgsField('Altitude', QVariant.String))
layerFields.append(QgsField('Notes', QVariant.String))
```

I've tried setting QVariant to int and converting the float values to ints but still nothinng.

Comment: Did you try set `QVariant.Double` for your `QgsField` `Northing`, `Easting`, `Altitude` ? Did you also tried to do `[type(i) for i in dato.iloc[0].tolist()]` to be sure of type of each element in your list (sometimes what you see is not what you visually think it is)?

Comment: @ThomasG77 Yes I started with QVariant.Double actually. I've manually checked all their types but the results were: <class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'numpy.float64'>
<class 'str'> do you think it has to do with it being 'numpy.float64'?

Comment: Try using `item` method like described at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452775/converting-numpy-dtypes-to-native-python-types Normally, the following code `[i.item() if isinstance(i, numpy.generic) else i for i in dato.iloc[0].tolist()]` should work to cast all numpy objects to native Python types. I used in the previous expression `numpy.generic` but it can be `np.generic` depending if you've done numpy import with `import numpy` or `import numpy as np`

Comment: Conclusion? Did it works. Normally, with the native Python types instead of numpy, it should.

Comment: @ThomasG77 Yes! After doing a little research with the links you provided it managed to transform out of a numpy.float64 using .item() on the fields I needed to. Thanks so much for that pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @ThomasG77 pointed out, calling .item() on the attributes that were not transferring fixed the issue

```
['Transect'].iloc[y], int(filter_dato['Point Number'].iloc[y]), filter_dato['Subclass'].iloc[y], \
                         filter_dato['Northing'].iloc[y].item(), filter_dato['Easting'].iloc[y].item(), filter_dato['Altitude'].iloc[y].item(), \
                         filter_dato['Notes'].iloc[y]
```